# SocketIO not updating in real time?

Tags: socket.io

I'm trying to get used to SocketIO and realtime data transfering.

I made this simple frontend implementation which emits an event to the server, and the server updates my age plus 10. But this is not updating on the multiple connections I have from the frontend, it's just updating the window where I make the event.

Client side

```js
function handleEmit() {
        console.log('Emitting...', person);
        socket.emit('new-ops', JSON.stringify(person));
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('new-remote-ops', (data) => {
            console.log('Listening new-remote-ops');
            setPerson({ ...JSON.parse(data) });
        });
    }, [])
```

Server side

```js
io.on('connect', socket => {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('new-ops', data => {
        const data2 = JSON.parse(data);
        socket.emit('new-remote-ops', JSON.stringify({ name: data2.name, age: data2.age + 10 }), (err) => console.log(err));
    })
})
```

EDIT:
`package.json` file here of server

```json
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "socket.io": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

`package.json` file of client:

```json
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.4.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**EDIT #2:**
As stated Pascal's answer, I changed `socket.emit()` to `io.emit()` and now both connections receive something, but they are not receiving the data I want. As stated in the server code I attached, I want to add 10 to the age I'm receiving (The initial value is 1), so when I click on the button it should update the age from 1 to 1 + 10 and so on (Yes, I'm updating the state, but even when I `console.log()` the data I'm receiving, it's not 1 + 10 in the client, but it is on the server side)

My io implementation on the server after the changes

```js
io.on('connect', socket => {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('new-ops', data => {
        io.emit('new-remote-ops', { name: data.name, age: data.age + 10 });
    })
})
```

My client code

```js
const App = () => {
    const [person, setPerson] = React.useState({
        name: 'Sergio',
        age: 1
    });
    const [socketConnected, setSocketConnected] = React.useState(false);

    function handleEmit() {
        console.log('Emitting...', person);
        socket.emit('new-ops', person);
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('new-remote-ops', (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            setPerson({ name: data.name, age: data.age });
        });
    }, [])

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (!socket) return;

        socket.on('connect', () => setSocketConnected(true))

        socket.on('disconnect', () => setSocketConnected(false))
    }, [socket])
    return (
        <>
            <div>React App</div>
            <span>{socketConnected ? 'Connected' : 'Disconnected'}</span>
            <div />
            <button onClick={handleEmit}>Emit</button>
            <br />
            <span>{person.name}, {person.age}</span>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Provide package.json file both project.

Comment: You also send json while emit data.

Comment: @AshishKadam just added those files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use `socket.broadcast` / `io.emit` to send data to all connections

In your server-side code ...

```js
socket.on('new-ops', data => {
  const data2 = JSON.parse(data);
  socket.emit('new-remote-ops', JSON.stringify({
    name: data2.name,
    age: data2.age + 10
  }), (err) => console.log(err));
})
```

... you receive and send data to the same `socket`. This will always be the same `socket`.

If you want to receive data from individual sockets but repond to all available connections you have to use `broadcast` ([here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#flag-broadcast)) or `io.emit` ([here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#namespaceemiteventname-args))

Example

```js
// everyone gets it but the sender
socket.broadcast.emit("an event", { some: "data" });

// everyone gets it
io.emit("an event sent to all connected clients"); // main namespace
```

*Socket.io Version 4.x*

Comment: So, if I only use `socket.emit()` I'm sending data **only** to the socket that was connected. If I use `io.emit()` everyone gets it, but if I use `socket.broadcast.emit()` everyone but the sender gets it (This is the opposite from the `socket.emit()` from what I can read)

Comment: It is sending data to all of the connection, but it's not receiving the `age + 10`. I'll update the question

Comment: Oh, nevermind. I solved that by stringifying the data I'm sending.

Comment: Glad I could help !